# Ford Galaxy speed sensor

Tags: ford, galaxy

I am some real need of assistance please. I have been searching the internet and YouTube for months for help but to no avail.

I have a Ford Galaxy Titanium 2.0 Petrol Automatic which displays Speed Sensor Fault during diagnostics. I now believe the Speed Sensor may be called a Crankshaft or a Camshaft Sensor??

I would really appreciate if someone could share the location of this speed sensor as, other than locating the device, it looks a minor job to complete.

Photos or video would especially useful.

Thankyou for your time 
David

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Galaxy? Also, a speed sensor is different than a cam/crank *position* sensor. Speed sensor has to do with vehicle speed, not engine speed. And, what is the exact code which is being displayed during diagnostics?

Comment: Thank you for your response. My vehicle is a 2010 unfortunately we have misplaced the speed sensor error code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My vehicle is a 2010 unfortunately we have misplaced the speed sensor error code.